# Можно ли использовать цикл If, как While или рекурсия в If. Python

Tags: python, if

Допустим, у нас есть такая часть кода:

```
def test(lang):
  count = input("Сколько вопросов хотите задать")
```

Я создал функцию для проверки типа символов в строке. Являются ли символы числом или символами:

```
intcheck('25') вернет мне 'int'
intcheck('приветhello') вернет мне 'char'
```

Так вот, я хочу, чтобы он задавал этот вопрос, пока строка не будет числом.
У меня был вариант через `while`, но ему нужно условие до его работы, поскольку условие у меня определяется функцией, то 0 я ей присвоить не смогу. Подскажите
пару идей, как это можно сделать. Мне нужно что-то на подобии этого:

```
if intcheck(count) != 'int':
    print('Введите число, пожалуйста')
```

И здесь программа должна вернуться на шаг назад. Именно на шаг, а не в начало функции и попросить ввести еще раз.

Comment: https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/

Comment: @Степан используй While True:, а как только найдешь нужный тип (или элемент), используй команду break для выхода из цикла

Answer (score 9):

While тут вполне можно использовать:

```
while True:
    count = input("Сколько вопросов хотите задать")
    if intcheck(count) == 'int':
        break
    else:
        print('Введите число, пожалуйста')
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92348/discussion-on-answer-by------if--while--).